# boost.asio test problem

Tags: c++, windows-xp, boost-asio

I'm new on boost.asio.
I have a problem when I try a simple example.

in my header file I have:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include "boost/bind.hpp"
#include "boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_types.hpp"
```

and I need this private variable:

```
boost::asio::ip::udp::socket socket_;
```

I have this error at compile time:

```
error C2512: 'boost::asio::basic_datagram_socket<Protocol>' : no appropriate default constructor available
        with
        [
            Protocol=boost::asio::ip::udp
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The list of all UDP socket constructors if [found here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_datagram_socket/basic_datagram_socket.html). As you can see, you must provide at least a reference to a `boost::asio::io_service` object.

If this is a private variable, provide this reference in the class constructor's initializer list. The following will compile:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
class Socket
{
    boost::asio::ip::udp::socket socket_;
 public:
    Socket( boost::asio::io_service& ioserv) : socket_(ioserv) {}
};
int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service io;
    Socket s(io);
}
```

Comment: Is there a doc why boost::asio was designed like this? For me this is quite inconvenient.

Comment: @Simon It's in the name: "asio" means asynchronous I/O. That library simply doesn't have a synchronous-only socket class, and in order to support async operations, the socket needs a reference to io_service. Even if you're only planning to call sync operations.

Answer (score 1):

I have used boost::asio and I had a similar issue.

You need to make a constructor that takes a io_service object and initialize your socket_ with the io_service.

Like so:

```
tcp_connection::tcp_connection(boost::asio::io_service& io_service) : socket_(io_service) {}
```